# How to calculate Silhouette coefficient for k-mediod clustering using pyclustering lib?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, sklearn-pandas

I like try the k-mediod clustering method (PAM) over the dataset https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/seeds

I don't know whether there exists other libraries other than **pyclustering** for this purpose. Anyway, how can I compute **Silhouette coefficient** for the clustering using this library? It don't provide such a method as an k-means with sklearn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html), you can use `sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score(X, labels, metric=’euclidean’, sample_size=None, random_state=None, **kwds)`. This function returns the mean Silhouette Coefficient over all samples. To obtain the values for each sample, use `silhouette_samples`. I also recommend to see this [vignette](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_silhouette_analysis.html). There is a nice example in there for you to test too.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible via pyclustering since 0.8.2, here is an example from documentation:

```
from pyclustering.cluster.center_initializer import kmeans_plusplus_initializer
from pyclustering.cluster.kmeans import kmeans
from pyclustering.cluster.silhouette import silhouette

from pyclustering.samples.definitions import SIMPLE_SAMPLES
from pyclustering.utils import read_sample

# Read data 'SampleSimple3' from Simple Sample collection.
sample = read_sample(SIMPLE_SAMPLES.SAMPLE_SIMPLE3)

# Prepare initial centers
centers = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(sample, 4).initialize()

# Perform cluster analysis
kmeans_instance = kmeans(sample, centers)
kmeans_instance.process();
clusters = kmeans_instance.get_clusters()

# Calculate Silhouette score
score = silhouette(sample, clusters).process().get_score()
```

In case of PAM you need to change the last part:

```
...
medoids = kmeans_plusplus_initializer(sample, 4).initialize(return_index=True)
kmedoids_instance = kmedoids(sample, medoids)
clusters = kmedoids_instance.process().get_clusters()

score = silhouette(sample, clusters).process().get_score()
```